# Filtering locally rendered JSON table in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, react-native, filter

I have a page in my React App that renders some locally stored JSON Data into a table. I've been trying for a long time to implement a search bar that will filter through the PostCode column in the table and return the row. So far I've been able to make a search bar that does what I want it to but I haven't been able to integrate it into the page with the table.

My apologies if this is an easy question or I'm way off the mark. I'm a coding novice but have to use React for a project and struggle to get to grips with it.

The code for my table looks like this:

```
import SearchBar from './SearchBar'
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Data } from './NewData.js'

export const JsonReader = () => {
  return (
    <>
    
    <ArchiveHeader />

      <div className="data-container">Welcome to RF</div>
        {Data.map((data, key) => {
          return (
            <div key={key}>
            <JsonTable
            key = {key}
            Username = {data.Username}
            Address = {data.Address}
            PostCode = {data.PostCode}
            Details ={data.Details}
            Date ={data.Date}
            Score ={data.Score}
             />
             </div>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
};

const ArchiveHeader = () => {
  return (
    <header className="ArchiveHeader">
      <h2>Rent Flag</h2>
    </header>
  );
};

const JsonTable= ({ Username, Address, PostCode, Details, Date, Score }) => {
  if (!Username) return <div />;
  return (
    <table data={Data}>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h5>{Username}</h5>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h5>{Address}</h5>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h4>{PostCode}</h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>{Details}</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>{Date}</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p>{Score}</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
export default JsonReader;
```

and the code for my searchbar looks like this:

```
import Papa from "papaparse";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Data } from './NewData.js'
import JsonReader from './JsonReader'

export default function SearchBar () {
const [searchTerm,setSearchTerm] = useState('')
return (
  <div className="SearchBar">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search..." onChange={e=>setSearchTerm(e.target.value)} />
    {Data.filter((val)=>{
      if(searchTerm == ""){
        return val
      }
      else if(val.PostCode.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())){
        return val;
      }
    }).map((val,key)=>{
      return <div>{val.PostCode} </div>
    })}
  </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `useMemo` hook for this functionality.

```
const searchResults = useMemo(() => {
  if (!searchTerm) {
    return items;
  }

  return Data?.filter((item) =>
    item?.toLowerCase()?.includes(searchTerm?.toLowerCase().trim())
  );
}, [Data, searchTerm]);
```

You can use `searchResults` variable and render that in your table.

Answer (score 0):

In the same JsonReader function you should:

1. Create the useState constants `[searchTerm, setSearchTerm]`.
2. Set a new **FData** array with filtered data and that is the one you should do the mapping to.
3. Place the input field on the same page.
4. And, instead of using the *Data.map* you will use the **FData.map**.

This is how your **JsonReader** function should look like *(and the SearchBar function could be discarded)*:

```
export const JsonReader = () => {
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
    const FData = Data.filter((val) => {
    if (searchTerm == "") {
        return val;
    } else if (val.PostCode.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
        return val;
    }
    });
    return (
    <>
    
        <ArchiveHeader />

        <div className="data-container">Welcome to RF</div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="search..." onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)} />
        {FData.map((data, key) => {
        return (
            <div key={key}>
            <JsonTable
                key = {key}
                Username = {data.Username}
                Address = {data.Address}
                PostCode = {data.PostCode}
                Details ={data.Details}
                Date ={data.Date}
                Score ={data.Score}
            />
            </div>
        );
        })}
    </>
    );
};
```